# Angular JS dynamic dropdown selection based other drop down selections

Tags: angularjs

**Issue:**
 I was able to create group of dropdowns with ng repeat and ng-options and dropdown selected items are removed from the next dropdown.

The issue here is that it is not dynamic and works for predefined number of dropdowns.

Current logic works for three dropdowns and if i want to expand to another dropdown, there is an additional filter and dropdown changes in code

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="HelloCntl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:{name:'!Adam'}">
        <span>{{friend.name}}</span>
        <span>{{friend.phone}}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <select ng-model="selectname1" 
    ng-options="item as item.name for item in friends|filter:filter2|filter:filter3" ><option value="">- select -</option></select>
   <div>{{selectname1}}</div>

  <select ng-model="selectname2" 
      ng-options="item as item.name for item in friends|filter:filter1|filter:filter3" ><option value="">- select -</option></select>
   <div>{{selectname2}}</div>

  <select ng-model="selectname3" ng-options="item as item.name for item in friends|filter:filter1|filter:filter2" ><option value="">- select -</option></select>
   <div>{{selectname3}}</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[])

app.controller('HelloCntl',  
    function ($scope) {
    $scope.selectname1={};    
    $scope.selectname2={};    
    $scope.selectname3={};

    $scope.filter1 = function(item){
      return (!($scope.selectname1&&$scope.selectname1.id)||item.id !=$scope.selectname1.id);
    };

    $scope.filter2 = function(item){
      return (!($scope.selectname2&&$scope.selectname2.id)||item.id!=$scope.selectname2.id);
    };
    $scope.filter3 = function(item){
      return (!($scope.selectname3&&$scope.selectname3.id)||item.id !=$scope.selectname3.id);
    };
    $scope.friends = [
      {
        id:1,name: 'John',
        phone: '555-1276'},
      {
        id:2,name: 'Mary',
        phone: '800-BIG-MARY'},
      {
        id:3,name: 'Mike',
        phone: '555-4321'},
      {
        id:4,name: 'Adam',
        phone: '555-5678'},
      {
        id:5,name: 'Julie',
        phone: '555-8765'}

    ];


})
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/bBjmqx

Comment: What is the question here ? Please elaborate more

Comment: I am trying to loop through and make it dynamic based on the length of the array of objects instead defining prdefined length. Current logic works only for three dropdowns